# First extjs example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm want to learn extjs so I'm a newbie, so sorry for any stupid question here..

Here is my index.html page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Hello</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs-4.2.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs-4.2.1-gpl/ux/form/LoginForm.js"></script>
<!-- <link href="extjs-4.1.1a/KitchenSink-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
<link href="extjs-4.2.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id= "content"  >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var loginForm = Ext.create("test.view.form.LoginForm", {
                id : "panellogin", 
                renderTo : 'content'
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And LoginForm :

```
Ext.define('test.view.form.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype : "test.view.form.LoginForm",
    title: 'Login',
    frame:true,
    width: 320,
    bodyPadding: 20,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.items = [me.contentPanel];
        me.contentPanel = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
            border: true,
            align :"center",
            layout: {
                type: "hbox",
                align: "center"
            },
            items: [
                    {
                        allowBlank: false,
                        fieldLabel: 'User ID',
                        name: 'user',
                        emptyText: 'user id'
                    },
                    {
                        allowBlank: false,
                        fieldLabel: 'Password',
                        name: 'pass',
                        emptyText: 'password',
                        inputType: 'password'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'checkbox',
                        fieldLabel: 'Remember me',
                        name: 'remember'
                    }
                    ]
        });
    }
});
```

What did I exactly is:

1. Downloaded extjs 4.2.1-gpl from sencha website (about 65 Mo compressed)
2. When I found the huge size I delete things like examples, docs
3. Moved src inside a directory named ux inside 4.2.1-gpl directory
4. Kept resources, images and locale folders.

I need advice please, is this a good way to do? I can't put the whole content since it is more than 300 Mio! What to keep, please?

Firebug is showing me this error : `TypeError: c is undefined (in ext-all.js line 21)`
Google chrome is showing this : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Kind regards,

Could you please tell what's happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your code after the extjs sources are loaded ([Ext.onReady](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-onReady)...):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var loginForm = Ext.create("test.view.form.LoginForm", {
        id : "panellogin", 
        renderTo : 'content'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not like you should have done. Especially deleting stuff and renaming src to ux. Also a class definition of `test.view.form.LoginForm` should be in the file `app/view/form/LoginForm.js`, not `ux/form`.

Read the doc how to get started, especially [MVC Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture) and the [App Architecture Series](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/mvc_pt1).